# Title in navigation bar too long on smaller screens; set font sizes for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

I made an iOS app. One view has a web view and a navigation bar. I've trouble with the navigation bar. On iPhone 6s the title in the navigation bar is "This is my app!". But on iPhone 5s the title in the navigation bar is "This is my a…". It's because the iPhone 5s screen is't as wide as the iPhone 6s plus screen, so my header is too long.

Is there a possibility to auto shrink the text or set an own font size or other header for iPhone 5s (and other devices)?

I googled nearly all day but could't find any helpful hint.
Does anybody have an idea? Please help me!

Here's a screenshot from iPhone 5s: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6QZM.png)

Comment: is there any item set in navigation bar? "< Back" button maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Also you can try this too:

```
label.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following example.

```
NSDictionary *size = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil];

UINavigationController* navigationController = [self navigationController];
[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, YOUR_WIDH, YOUR_HEIGHT)];
lbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"FONT_NAME" size:FONT_SIZE];
lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.text=@"YOUR_TITLE";
self.navigationItem.titleView=lbl;
```

Hope this helps.